# Entity framework com string de conexão via código

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e preciso que a string de conexão seja definido no próprio código, pois não pode haver o arquivo app.config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para isto basta passar a sua *string de conexão* no construtor do seu contexto.

Por exemplo:

```
public class MeuDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MeuDbContext(): base("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=meudb;User Name=usuario;Password=senha;")
    {
       ......
       ......
    }
}
```

É possível também fazer o mesmo passando-se uma `DbConnection`, inicializando-a antes de passa-la como parâmetro.

Espero ter ajudado!